# linux ps show where process is running from

Tags: linux, process

Is it possible, using `ps`, to determine where a process is running from?

I have two applications, both are identical and running in parallel directories, such as `/app1/start.sh` and `/app2/start.sh`. If I run `ps -ef` then I'm unable to tell the difference between the two

Using `ps` (or alternative), how can I tell that PID 123 belongs to app1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some examples:

Current process list presented in tree hierarchy and wide output (showing the full command line arguments and not cutting them after X characters) `ps -auxwwwf`

Command `pstree`, show all processes and their process id's: `pstree -ap`

Or, if you are only interested in PIDs: `pgrep -f app1` would list you all the PIDs for the processes matching pattern `app1` somewhere along their name, command line arguments or path.

Comment: pgrep works for me. I'll have to predefine which PIDs are excluded from killing, but that'll work. thanks

Comment: Great. :) Remember, there's also `pkill` which works the same way than `pgrep`, but instead of grep it kills.

Comment: Very very late comment - the dash/hyphen is used to select SVR4 type flags. But you have BSD flags... skip the hyphen and just use ‘ps auxwwwf’. Also I don’t think the third w does anything.. I think the second already does “go as wide as you need”

Comment: @RichHomolka: Two w's chooses 16:9 display ratio whereas three w's means 21:9 display ratio. Naah. Just kidding. You are correct, my past me apparently got overly excited about the w's.

Answer (score 3):

Also look at the `/proc/` filesystem.  In `/proc/*pid*` you have:

- `exe` which is a symlink to the
  executable binary.  In case of a
  script, this is the interpreter (/bin/bash) not the script.
- `cwd`
  which is a symlink to the current
  directory of the process
- `cmdline`
  which is a NUL separated
  representation of the command line

you also have a list of current file descriptors.  I find `/proc/*pid*/fd/255` useful in bash scripts - it's a symlink to the script itself.

ps looks at /proc/ to find info, so there may be some magic incantation of flags that shows some of these - look at `ps -o`

Answer (score 2):

Try

> ps auxf

This gives you the hierarchy of the processes.